# Scanner error in Code, building array using reference variables

Tags: java

I'm still pretty new to coding, so my apologies if this has an obvious fix.

I'm trying to build a library that can store book objects, but before I can work on functionality, I need to get an array sorted out. Java itself does not show any errors in my side bar, but  when ran through the console, an error appears.

Below I have posted my Library.java class.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Library {
 
 public static void main(String[] args){
  
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  Book[] books = new Book[2];
  String Title;
  String Author;
     String BookID;
  Boolean onLoan;
  int NumberofLoans;
  
  for( int i = 0; i < books.length; i++){
   System.out.print("Enter the title of the book: ");
   Title = input.next();
   books[i] = new Book();
   books[i].setTitle(Title);
   System.out.println("");
   
   System.out.print("Enter the Author of the book: ");
   Author = input.next();
   books[i].setAuthor(Author);
   System.out.println("");
   
   System.out.print("Enter the Book's ID: ");
   BookID = input.next();
   books[i].setBookID(BookID);
   System.out.println("");
   
   NumberofLoans = 0;
   books[i].setNumberofLoans(NumberofLoans);
   
   onLoan = false;
   books[i].setonLoan(onLoan);
   
   input.close();
   }
  
  for(int i = 0; i < books.length; i++){
   System.out.println("Title: " + books[i].getTitle());
   System.out.println("Author: " + books[i].getAuthor());
   System.out.println("BookID: " + books[i].getBookID());
   System.out.println("Times loaned: " + books[i].getNumberofLoans());
   System.out.println("In library: " + books[i].getonLoan());
   
  } 
 }
}
```

The console error itself, is listed below:

```
Exception in thread "main" Enter the title of the book:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1070)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1358)
at Library.main(Library.java:19)
```

Could someone pin-point where in my code the error is coming from? Then, changes I could make to stop this error from occurring?

Just to make sure that everything is listed, I will post Book.java, in case the error originates from in there.

```
public class Book {

private String Title;
private String Author;
private String BookID;
private Boolean onLoan;
private int NumberofLoans;



public Book(){
    Title = new String();
    Author = new String();
    BookID = new String();
    onLoan = false;
    NumberofLoans = 0;

}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.Title = title;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.Author = author;
}

public void setBookID(String bookID) {
    this.BookID = bookID;
}

public void setonLoan(Boolean onLoan) {
    this.onLoan = onLoan;
}

public void setNumberofLoans(int numberofLoans) {
    this.NumberofLoans = numberofLoans;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return Author;
}

public String getBookID() {
    return BookID;
}

public Boolean getonLoan() {
    return onLoan;
}

public int getNumberofLoans() {
    return NumberofLoans;
}}
```

Comment: "_Could someone pin-point where in my code the error is coming from_"  Well, after reading the informative exception text `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed` I will guess the issue is when you CLOSE A SCANNER. Oh look, there's only 1 line with that... `input.close();`.

Comment: _"changes I could make to stop this error from occurring?"_ Stop closing your scanner after using it only one time in the loop. Close it AFTER you are done getting everything you want out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Library` class' first loop is causing this. Specifically, this line:

```
input.close();
```

Because you are closing the `Scanner` before it has been used completely by whole program. `Scanner` is available first time the loop runs. But after first execution, you close the scanner. Hence for the consecutive loop runs, scanner is closed and hence the error.

Add this line after loop finishes. In other words, something like this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < books.length; i++){
    // ... Whatever
}

input.close();
```